# Get Python without (selected) batteries

Tags: python, distribution

I very like the "battery included" philosophy of Python but now I have to perform a slim installation with only core features and some other which I'd like to choose one by one.

Is it possible to download Python with only selected modules?

Comment: Most of the core language features come from the standard library. Why would you want to omit them?

Comment: If not, it's easy enough to install normally and then remove all libraries you don't need. (Edit @jathanism: Please define "core language features", because in my book that's by definition not in libraries)

Comment: I have to make a small package to be sent via e-mail or downloaded. I see that there are some folders/libs that I do not use (test, docs, tcl) that take several MBs

Comment: Well, how critical are a very MB? Unless you're targeting something embedded, propably not at all. Yeah, it may seem pointless now, but you'll curse this decision the day you want to run something that needs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install python as normal. Open up the python interpreter and import some of the stuff you think you won't want.

```
import io, optparse, tarfile
```

Then the `str` representation of the module has its path in it

```
>>> tarfile
<module 'tarfile' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/tarfile.py'>
```

You can just go in and remove whatever `.py` files you dont want in your installation.

Obviously this is dangerous because you don't really know the internal dependencies of the Python modules.

Comment: It is not clear whether the OP meant to remove *stdlib* modules (other than tkinter).

Answer (score 2):

> I see that there are some folders/libs that I do not use (test, docs, tcl) that take several MBs

[ActivePython](http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads) does not include *tests*, and provides a install-time option to exclude *documentation* and PyWin32 (though not for tcl/tkinter - but you can safely delete it after install).

Alternatively you could use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create a customized installer for your app.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) or similar projects. They basically package a Python script with all its dependency in a single executable. It looks like it would be the right thing for you.

If I recall there's also an independent module in py2exe that recursively analyses the dependency of a Python module, I can't find it now though.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible to **download** Python with only selected modules, but after an install you can remove everything (read: the libraries) you don't need (never going to use JSON? Gone!, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can start from [TinyPy](http://code.google.com/p/tinypy/issues/list), and add what you needed. However, TinyPy seems to be unmaintained though.